# Configuração no WebView

Tags: java, android, xamarin

Boa tarde, tenho um aplicativo ( no xamarin para android) onde dentro dele abre uma webview em um link de uma plataforma de cursos que tenho... porém existe uma grande diferença entre eu abrir essa plataforma no meu webView e em um navegador como o chrome por exemplo...
No webView o vídeo da plataforma VIMEO, quando aperto play, não consigo depois pausar e nem deixar em fullscreen 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já no google chrome ( pelo mesmo aparelho ) , ja é possível dar pause, colocar em modo fullscreen etc...[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu preciso fazer de configuração no meu webview para ele não ter estes problemas? Obrigado

Segue trecho do código da activity do webview:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //MainActivity Url_Nav = new MainActivity();
            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Nav);
            mWebView = FindViewById(Resource.Id.webNav);
            mWebView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            mWebView.LoadUrl(MainActivity.url);
            mWebView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        }

    }

    public class WebClient1 : WebViewClient
    {
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
        {
            view.LoadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Obrigado !